# Cloning and displaying a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This is quite tricky. I have a table that is wider than the page, so the user has to scroll horizontally to see certain columns. But then they lose sight of the left-most (header) column.

I'm not in charge of the table structures (quite bizarre setup IMO), but it's like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[THE HEADER COLUMN (as a separate table)]</td>
        <td>[THE TABLE BODY (as a separate table)]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I need to display the 'header column table' on the edge of the screen when the user has scrolled this out of view, and mouses over to the edge of the screen.

I was thinking that cloning the header table then displaying it temporarily was the way to go about this (can't move the original, as page width would change). This seems like a bit of a messy solution (especially since the original column header table has IDs associated with it).

Do you think this is the right approach? Any ideas?

I **don't** need help with any of the jQuery event handling, and I **can't** use a scrollable table instead of this approach.

Comment: What happens when you give possition:absolute;top:0;left:0; to Table inside of Header Column?

Comment: @eugeneK If by (0,0) you mean visible page top left corner (i.e. ignoring scroll offset), then the table is moved as expected, but this causes the page width to change, thus the scroll offset, so things get a little crazy.

Comment: bring some example using jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the css of the first table to fixed and left to 0 then it would be glued to the left edge of the screen, you would just have to check that the user had started scrolling after every scroll event:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){ // fired after every scroll event
    if($(window).scrollLeft() > 0){ // check horizontal scroll
        $("#table1").css("position","fixed");
    } else {
        $("#table1").css("position","relative");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a css n00b, so I didn't know about `position:fixed`. Thanks so much for the response!